# GWT AbstractImagePrototype.create unclosed img tag

Tags: html, gwt

```
    html = AbstractImagePrototype.create(RESOURCES.icon()).getHTML();
```

Generates a string like this:

```
<img onload='this.__gwtLastUnhandledEvent="load";' src='http://localhost:8083/home/s/clear.cache.gif' style='width:16.0px;height:15.0px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,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) no-repeat 0px 0px;' border='0'>
```

However, notice the img tag isn't closed. When I add this to an html template, and try closing it by putting `</img>` at the end, the close tag gets stripped. The lack of the close tag causes it to display the string

How can I get it to close the img tag w/o a silly string manipulation?

Comment: I don't think that a missingclose tag will make a browser display the source.

Comment: Which DocType do you use?

Comment: The problem actually stemmed from not using SafeHtml as the image parameter on the html template. Beware what Christian mentions about the unseen escaping that happens, which firebug basically hides from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may use this method the wrong way.

You are getting a html-string if u call `getHTML()`. How do you add this String to you DOM?

The normal way would be to call something like:

```
FlowPanel fp = new FlowPanel();
fp.add(AbstractImagePrototype.create(RESOURCES.icon()));
```

This will add the image to the document.

**update**

If you want to use this string inside a SafeHtmlBuild you have to wrap you String.

SafeHtmlBuilder will espape < to &gt; and > to &lt; I think you will have to wrap the image with [SafeHtmlUtils#fromTrustedString](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/safehtml/shared/SafeHtmlUtils.html#fromTrustedString%28java.lang.String%29). Because otherwise it wil be escapted twice.

Comment: I'm in a render method, using SafeHtmlBuilder.

Comment: It works perfectly fine, except for the missing closing tag. I can see this in firebug (in fact I pasted this from firebug), adding the single slash fixes it. I just don't understand why its not being generated properly, seems like a bug. Also, using a html template seems to delete my added </img> tag, which also seems strange to me.

Comment: Joel, you are probably using the wrong SafeHtmlBuilder append method - even bad html will be properly printed if you use the appendHtmlConstant method. If you use `appendEscaped`, it will escape that text no matter what, and will display literal `<`, `>` chars instead of rendered content.

Comment: The render method escapes and a safeHtmlBuilder escapes too. Sou your String is escaped twice.

Comment: The template method returns SafeHtml, and I call safeHtmlBuilder.append()

Comment: Yes, but the AbstractImagePrototype.create(RESOURCES.icon()).getHTML() returns a String, no SafeHtml. Use http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/AbstractImagePrototype.html#getSafeHtml() instead of getHTML()

Comment: I asked it to display the value of html (from above)...

it is <img ..blah blah blah.. >, with no ending slash/tag... I don't understand why I'm worried about safeHtmlBuilder here?? It is getting that string into the browser just fine, I just need it to close the tag. Ill probably just add the slash myself, but thought there was something I'm missing.

Comment: so 1) html = AbstractImagePrototype.create(RESOURCES.icon()).getHTML() 2) sb.append(template.myrenderedblock(html, ...) that's really it.

Comment: We are talking about the SafeHtmlBuilder because, it is really hard to see with firebug or chrome debugger if there is <img or &gt;img transmittet. I would bet that firebug will mislead you. Try the other render, or use Fiddler to ensure, that there is REALLY no double-escaping. I had a issue like this in a chrome browser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23254/discussion-between-christian-kuetbach-and-joel)